# Core Data: Save edits to persistent store

Tags: ios, core-data

I think I know the answer to this but not sure.  And I don't have a good way to check as it is not yet working properly, so am therefore asking question.

To display a user profile stored in core data's persistent store i.e. sqllite database, I fetch an object corresponding to the user from an entity or table of userinfo using NSpredicate.  This pulls up one user and loads it into the managed objectcontext so i can display it.  So far so good.

However, to edit the information, is it the case that I merely need to change the information in the managedobjectcontext and save and do not need to have any equivalent of the WHERE clause in the save.  In other words, is it enough to do following:

```
[self.user setValue:_description forKey:@"descript"];
 if ([self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"we saved");
      }
```

Without specifying which managed object or row in persistent store we are editing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer - yes, it is enough to call `save:`. As long as the changed object is a member of the receiving `managedObjectContext` and the call returns `YES` the save has been done.

`NSManagedObjectContext` neither knows nor cares about its backing store type.

`NSPersistentStore` is the thing that knows about its backing store type and deals with the mechanics of transacting with the SQLite database when it's set to `NSSQLiteStoreType`

You can have 3 types of backing store on `iOS` and 4 on `OS X` and stores of all those types can be loaded into the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` at the same time. Probably not a good idea but technically possible.

If you are feeling particularly adventurous you can make your own store type via `NSIncrementalStore`.